# Redundant methods across several unit tests/classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Say in the main code, you've got something like this:

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<Obj1> create(List<ObjA> list) {
        return (new MyClassCreator()).create(list);
    }
    // Similar methods for other CRUD operations
}
```

**MyClassCreator.java**

```
public class MyClassCreator {
    Obj1Maker obj1Maker = new Obj1Maker();

    public List<Obj1> create(List<ObjA> list) {
        List<Obj1> converted = new List<Obj1>();
        for(ObjA objA : list)
            converted.add(obj1Maker.convert(objA));
        return converted;
    }
}
```

**Obj1Maker.java**

```
public class Obj1Maker {
    public Obj1 convert(ObjA objA) {
        Obj1 obj1 = new Obj1();
        obj1.setProp(formatObjAProperty(objA));
        return obj1;
    }

    private String formatObjAProperty(ObjA objA) { 
        // get objA prop and do some manipulation on it
    }
}
```

Assume that the unit test for Obj1Maker is already done, and involves a method `makeObjAMock()` which mocks complex object A.

My questions:

1. For unit testing MyClassCreator, how would I test `create(List<ObjA> list)`? All the method really does is delegate the conversion from `ObjA` to `Obj1` and runs it in a loop. The conversion itself is already tested. If I were to create a list of `ObjA` and tested each object in the list of `Obj1` I get back, I would have to copy `makeObjAMock()` into MyClassCreator's unit test. Obviously, this would be duplicate code, so **is using `verify()` enough to ensure that create(List list) works?**
2. For unit testing MyClass, again, its `create(List<ObjA>)` method just delegates the operation to MyClassCreator. Do I actually need to test this with full test cases, or should I just verify that MyClassCreator's `create` method was called?
3. In the unit test for Obj1Maker, I checked that the properties Obj1 and ObjA corresponded to each other by doing `assertEquals(obj1.getProp(), formatObjAProperty(objA))`. However, that means I had to duplicate the code for the private `formatObjAProperty` method from the Obj1Maker class into its unit test. How can I prevent code repetition in this case? I don't want to make this method public/protected just so I can use it in a unit test. Is repetition acceptable in this case?

Thanks, and sorry for the lengthy questions.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is here. Picking which methods to test is a hard thing to do.

You have to think about a) whether you are meeting your requirements and b) what could go wrong when someone stupid makes changes to the code in the future. (Actually, the stupid person could be you. We all have bad days.)

I would say, writing new code to verify the two objects have the same data in two formats would be a good idea. Probably there is no reason to duplicate the code from the private method and copying the code over is a bad idea. Remember that you are verifying requirements. So if the original string said "6/30/13" and the reformatted one said "June 30th 2013", I would just hard code the check:

```
assertEquals("Wrong answer", "June 30th 2013", obj.getProp());
```

Add some more asserts for edge cases and errors. (In my example, use "2/30/13" and "2/29/12" and "12/1/14" to check illegal date, leap year day and that it gets "1st" not "1th" perhaps.)

In the test on the create method, I would probably just go for the easy error and verify that the returned array had the same number as the one passed in. The one I passed in would have two identical elements and some different ones. I'd just check that the identical ones came back identical and the different ones non-identical. Why? Because we already know the formatter works.

I wouldn't test the constructor but would make sure some test ran the code in it. It's good to make sure most of the code actually runs in a test to catch dumb errors like null pointers you missed.

The balance point is what you are looking for.

Enough tests, testing enough different things, to feel good about the code working.

Enough tests, testing obvious things, that stupid changes in the future will get found.

Not so many tests that the tests take forever to run and all the developers (including you) will put off running them because they don't want to wait or lose their train of thought while they run.

Balance!